# How do I add mobx typescript support?

Tags: typescript, mobx

[image]

As what you can see, the "replace" method is not support by ts.
Maybe I should use IObservableArray instead of Array, but another problem occurred.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at [mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-typescript-boilerplate)? It might give some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions. but yes you should use `IObservableArray` so you make sure you have and use the right methods.

I used this work around:

```
 this.files = [] as any;
```

or a more cast type once solution:

```
 function MyArray<T>(): IObservableArray<T> {
     return [] as any; // disable eslint once here.
 }

 this.files = MyArray();
```

### Advised solution

This issue was discussed before on github: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/669

The solution provided is to set it as readonly property once:

```
class AppModel {
  readonly files = observable<IFile>([])
}
```

this is the shortest typed solution that also makes sure you wont set `this.files` again mistakenly (and losing all your observers).

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is not mobx or typescript, you are using a method that does not exist on the Array object type. What are you expecting this "replace" method to do on an array?